# Android Hardware Menu button code not working properly! need help

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button, menu

I love this site all you guys are awesome! but here is another problem I have:
In my app I have a webview that displays a website in the entire screen, I have made a code to show a menu through pushing the phone's menu button from where i want 2 things to happen 1st menu item Go back to main screen of the app, 2nd menu item quit the app or exit the app.
First problem:
after pressing the menu button it shows the menu... if I press it again it shows the two choices twice, if I press it again now both items shows 3 times and so on!
Second Problem:
after choosing any of the two choices nothing happens!
here is my code please tell me what I'm doing wrong!
Thanks

menu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
android:id="@+id/menuToMenu"
android:title="Menu Principal"
/>
<item
android:id="@+id/menuToSalir"
android:title="Salir"
/>
</menu>
```

Backtomain.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Backtomain extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

and where I call the menu:

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater mostrar = getMenuInflater();
        mostrar.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
        }

    public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menuToMenu:
            startActivity (new Intent("my.app.BACKTOMAIN"));
            return true;
        case R.id.menuToSalir:
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `super.onCreateOptionsMenu()` from `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. And, you are inflating the same options into the menu in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. Rename `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` to `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, and it will probably behave better.

Also:

- If you think the `my.app.BACKTOMAIN` activity is running, you probably want to add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` or `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to the `Intent`.
- Get rid of the `menuToSalir` menu choice. No well-written Android application will call `System.exit(0)`. Users leave your application by pressing the HOME button, no different than they might in a Web app.

Comment: @ CommonsWave I did change the onPrepareOptionsMenu() to onCreateOptionsMenu() and it is working better I get the same to menus everytime I click the menu button, but in the other FLAG_REORDER-TO_FRONT or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to the Intent. Can you explain me a little more maybe with a sample? thanks

Comment: @zvzej: `Intent i=new Intent("my.app.BACKTOMAIN"); i.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); startActivity(i);`

Comment: it's giving me an error to solve it is asking me if I want to create a variable constant or fiel for the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: @zvzej: Ah, sorry, that should be `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`.

Comment: Yes that quote does not give an error, but when I press the menu choice it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your first problem try onCreateOptionsMenu(), rather than onPrepareOptionsMenu().

I am not positive how to fix second problem, I usually create my menus all in java instead of using xml like you have.

Comment: Can you explain me or give an example of coding it on java or where can I find one. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem it works! I was missing the "s" at...

```
public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item){
```

the right way is

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
```

thanks for your help Tim and CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem. In my case I had set the background color of the activity screen to black. When the menu popped up it had a transparent background and black text so I didn't see it working.